# Is it inappropriate to use ASP.net Identity Model Claims to map relationships between records in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am aware that ASP.net Identity Model is generally used to authenticate whether a user is permitted to access a specific resource/ endpoint. I have not found any examples of anybody doing what I have done, and I have decided that I am probably setting off down a path of misery and betrayal.

I have an example of what I am attempting with my claims-based record queries.

1. A user requests for all of his clients
2. a list of clientIds that my current user is a manager of is returned
3. we retrieve all those clients, and go and get their portfolio-related claims
4. we then go and retrieve all the portfolios that x client has a claim on
5. Build up response and ship it off.

```cs
public async Task<IList<Client>> GetUserClients(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var clientIds = claims.Where(c => c.Type.Equals(MyClaims.ClientManager)).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();

    var clients = new List<Client>();
    foreach (var clientId in clientIds)
    {
        var clientUser = await _userService.GetUserById(clientId);
        var client = Client.MapFromUser(clientUser);
        
        var clientPortfolioClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(clientUser);
        var clientPortfolioIds = clientPortfolioClaims.Where(c => c.Type.Equals(MyClaims.PortfolioViewer)).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();

        foreach (var portfolioId in clientPortfolioIds)
        {
            client.Portfolios.Add(await _userPortfolioService.GetUserPortfolioById(Int32.Parse(portfolioId), ""));
        }

        clients.Add(client);
    }

    return clients;
}
```

So instead of using normal RDS relations or columns, I am using an unenforceable relationship entries, probably in an abusive way.

I know what I am doing is possible as it *works*... but is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several processes to consider.

Authentication logs a user into a system.

Authorisation indicates what they can do once they have access to the system

Authorisation can be segregated by role, but these days the notion of Claims is often used.

As an example, Each portfolio is associated with a claim. To make the system more flexible, there might be a separate claim for reading the portfolio, editing it, printing it and so on (any general action you might want).

You then associate each claim with one or more users. You night have just one person who owns/edits the portfolio from a business perspective, but others may be able to look at it. If a person goes on holiday, you might give a another edit claim to another user, so now both the person going on holiday can edit the portfolio as well as the second person.

You can see that the problem of authorisation is reduced to mapping some object in the business to some person who logs in.

Now, for historic purposes, if a user edits a record in in the business data, it is valid to store the ID of that person. This is either the Identity ID or another ID in the business DB that maps to an identity user.

Hope that is useful